# Java Evaluate the least number out of many variables

Tags: java

I have four variables that I will not know until I call on the function but I need to determine out of the four variables which one is the least. Is there quick way to to do this without a lot of if else statements or is that the only way? If there equal then that needs to be returned to.

```
int TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT;

String MIN;

 min(TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT)
{
     FOUND MINNUM;
     return MINSTRING;
}
```

I realized that if there are multiple equal values that I need to return consistently the same equal value and the only way I can return it consistently if I return the string of the direction that is equal that is choosen to be min. Then I can check the string rather the integer to be more accurate.

Comment: Put them in a `Collection` and sort... Of course it will not tell which variable holds the minimum value, but which is the minimum value.

Comment: You have to use some form of comparaison to do it, either with `if else if ...` or tertiary writing, or with some sorting method and taking the first or last index..

Comment: Guava's [`Ints.min()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#min(int...))

Comment: apply quick sort. best way for 4 no.

Comment: You can use built-in classes like `Math`, `Collections`, and so forth. But for 4 variables, none of them will yield any better performance than simple `if/else`. So unless you have some knowledge on the possible range of each number, the minimal way to do it will be using 3 comparison operations.

Comment: Could you please add some example for the updated function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use nested `Math.min`s:

```
int min(int top, int bottom, int left, int right) {
    return Math.min(Math.min(top, bottom), Math.min(left, right));
}
```

Also, you may introduce more common method:

```
int min(Integer... nums) {
    if (nums.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("???");
    int res = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; ++i)
        res = Math.min(res, nums[i]);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 8 you can, and should, use the following:

```
int min = IntStream.of(TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT).min().getAsInt();
```

This uses streams, on which you can operate.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
private int least(Integer... values) {
    return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(values));
}
```

Comment: Not compilable. You need to actually make a Collection out of the array.

Comment: The method min(Collection<? extends T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Integer[])

Answer (score 0):

```
static int min(int... array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    return array[0];
}
```

Comment: Generally too slow (O(n logn)), but may be acceptable in this case. Also, this method is incorrect if one would pass the existing array into it, but, again, in this case, it may be ok.

Comment: Wrong algorithmic solution. Also, empty array -> NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, or something.